# jQuery - .attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube, attributes

Built a WordPress plugin that creates a custom-styled video player, based on a shortcode that contains the You Tube video id, and it works well. But now I have to convert it to allow multiple videos on the same page. So I'm grabbing all the player elements by class name, then getting their ids. The YouTube video id is appended to each player with a `data-id` attribute. In the single-video version of the plugin, I can use `$(#playerid).att('data-id')` to grab the attribute. Two strange things have happened in v2.0... The first is that I can no longer use `$` to specify jQuery objects, because WordPress uses compatibility mode (maybe I should be wondering why I COULD use $ in the previous version...), but that's easy to work around. The second, where I'm stuck, is that I can't use `attr`. It says that

> attr is not a function.

**I have tried .attr('data-id'), .data('id'), and converting to vanilla .getAttribute, but nothing works.** I have checked that the variable is pointing to the correct object, but I can't get its attribute... Any help?

I'll just post the first lines, where everything checks out until you get to `attr`...

```
var playerids = [];
var players = document.getElementsByClassName("video-player");

for (x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
    playerids[x] = players[x].id;
}

//for each vidid, create a player
for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

    var video_id = jQuery(playerids[i]).attr('data-id');
}
```

NEW INFO:
Changed a global variable from Vanilla to jQuery, and now I can use .attr or .data on the global variable. Here's my new, working code...why does this work, when the local varible didn't?

```
//find all player divs
var players = jQuery(".video-player");

//get the player div ids
var playerids = [];
for (x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
    playerids[x] = players[x].id;
}

//for each player div, get vidid and create player
for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

    var this_video = jQuery(players[i]).data('id');
```

Comment: have you included jquery library?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code :

```
var video_id = jQuery('#' + playerids[i]).attr('data-id');
```

Because  playerids[i] have only the play id like "playerid"

Answer (score 0):

What is obviously wrong in your code is assigning an id selector without a `#` sign at `jQuery(playerids[i]).attr('data-id');`

The correct syntax should be:
`jQuery('#' + playerids[i]).attr('data-id');`

If using `id` selector is not implicit, try this instead:

```
jQuery( ".video-player" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + jQuery(this).attr('data-id') );
});
```

Comment: Ouch - not appending the '#' is painfully obvious, in retrospect... But even with that added, it still tells me that .attr (or .data) is not a function.

Comment: Using console.log I can see the proper values echoed in the console, but I'm not familiar with that method -- how can I retrieve those values in my function? (And is that method good practice?)